# SQL Server 2008 R2 disable login from Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, security, sql-server-2008-r2

I understand that the reason mixed mode allows login with Windows authentication is for security purposes.  My boss asked me to create a `setup.exe` that installs:

1. our medical software
2. SQL Server 2008 R2
3. SQL Server Management Studio

The install is fully automated with limited user input. SQL Server and the SSMS are implemented with a config file. `sa` and `serviceRXuser` (strong passwords) are SQL Server authentication logins.

I don't want my clients to have access to our database, because editing drug data could be potentially life threatening. And yes, we have had clients alter things in our database... causing application errors that required re-installation.

Is there any way to, at least, limit access to keep end-users from editing the data? Preferably a T-SQL command so I can keep automation. If not, is there any way to hide the database?

Comment: what is the application user? SA or ServiceRXUser ? You have two types of Authentication , `Mix mode(Windows & Sql Server)` and Only `Windows Authentication` there is no setting which only allows only SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: serviceRXuser uses ODBC to connect app to sql server

Comment: right then make sure `serviceRXuser` has the minimum permissions to do what it needs to do and keep your SA password away from your clients. I don't get that why we put a lot of red-buttons out there and then expect people to not touch them :)

Comment: Could I use something like:  
'USE [master]'  
'GO'  
'DENY CONNECT TO SQL [(_local_)\system]'  
'GO'

Answer (score 0):

first of all, don't share SA password (on any strong user password) with your clients :)

Your app is running on client machines and coonnect to SQL via ODBC?

hmmm.... it is hard, because the users can use Your ODBC connection from ACCESS and EXCEL too. Can you change Your app to don't use ODBC?

If You grant ONLY exec rights on stored procedures to *serviceRXuser* (don't need DB_DATAREADER or any other rights), then clients can't do anything, only what You can handle in SP-s. You can send an encoded parameter to every SP, and decode is wrong, raise any random error SQL ;) Users can't create this encoding from excel/access ;)

Comment: thanks for the response.  I see your point and have taken it into consideration.  The problem I am trying to address is that when I install SSMS on a clients pc who has ADMINISTRATIVE rights, all they have to do is select Login with WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION, then they have full view and rights to my database.  If there is any way to hide or deny access upon installation I am in need of that process.

Comment: just for clear, You are logged in on a pc (workstation) with windows acc, (example dom\usr) and you install the SQL server to a server. dom\usr is admin on server and sysdamin in SQL. in this case, You need to create a new SQL login after the install, (example GOD) and grant sysadmin rights to GOD. then login to SQL with GOD and revoke sysadmin from dom\usr and server\adminimistrators. Next time, You need to access SQL with sysadmin rights, use GOD, instead of dom\usr. In his case, dom\usr and adminisitrators are NOT sysadmins, only GOD is sysadmin. users on PC not know GOD's password.